# Region plot with region function

Tags: plotting, regions

I am pretty new to mathematica (very new) and am trying to make a plot to display regions of a function that are positive and negative subject to a constraint.

I have a function $P = P(n,m)$ that has positive and negative values in regions of an $(n,m)$ plot. However the function is only valid for some constraint $\sigma=\sigma(n,m)$.

I have tried to do this in two ways but neither really highlights the boundary of where the function takes positive and negative values.
The first way is using

```
ContourPlot[P, {n, 0, 5}, {m, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 100, RegionFunction -> Function[{n, m}, sigma > 0], ColorFunction -> "GreenPinkTones"]
```

but doing it this way results in the following which does not really highlight the boundary between positive and negative.

[image: contour plot]

The second way I have tried is to use  `RegionPlot` as follows

```
RegionPlot[{P > 0, P < 0}, {n, 0, 10}, {m, 0, 10}, BoundaryStyle -> {Dashed, Dashed}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

In this case though I am not sure how to apply the $\sigma$ constraint of where the plot is valid. It ends up looking like

[image]

I think I would probably prefer the contour plot version if I could force the contour colouring to be distinct and normalised around zero but either (or both) methods would be awesome.

Any help here would be much appreciated!!

edit*1

$P$ looks like

[image]

Comment: Please provide $P$ so we can help you.

Comment: @David G. Stork Sure added for one case. I can not add in general what it looks as there are a lot of calculations involved in getting to this.

Comment: What is `uzhat`  and `$\sigma$` in your equation.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[p, sigma]
p[n_, m_] := -(1/(m n (m^2 + n^2)^(5/2) Sqrt[4 + m^2 + n^2])) (2.5 10^-7)
 (32.8634 m^4 - n^2 (4 + n^2) Sqrt[(m^2 + n^2) (4 + m^2 + n^2)] + 
   3 m^2 n^2 (10.9545 - Sqrt[(m^2 + n^2) (4 + m^2 + n^2)])) (9.8696 m n - 
     Cos[Pi (m + n)] Sin[m Pi] Sin[n Pi]);
sigma[n_, m_] := n^2 + m^2;
```

1. You can use `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to add a mesh line at `p[n ,m] == 0`:

```
ContourPlot[p[n, m], {n, 0, 5}, {m, 0, 5}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 50,
  MeshFunctions -> {p[#, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thick] , 
  RegionFunction -> (1/16 <= sigma[#, #2] <= 5 &), 
  ColorFunction -> "GreenPinkTones"]
```

[image]

2. You can create two `ContourPlot`s (the second one with a single contour at `0`) and combine them with `Show`:

```
{cp1, cp2} = ContourPlot[p[n, m], {n, 0, 5}, {m, 0, 5}, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
     Contours -> #, ContourShading -> #2,
     RegionFunction -> (1/16 <= sigma[#, #2] <= 5 &), 
     ColorFunction -> "GreenPinkTones"] & @@@
   {{30, Automatic}, {{{0, Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Thick]}}, None}};

Show[cp1, cp2]
```

[image]

2. You can post-process the `ContourPlot` output to re-style the contour corresponding to 0:

```
ContourPlot[p[n, m], {n, 0, 5}, {m, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 50, 
    RegionFunction -> (1/16 <= sigma[#, #2] <= 5 &), 
    ColorFunction -> "GreenPinkTones"] /. Tooltip[{___, l_Line}, 0. | 0] :> 
  Tooltip[{Opacity[1, Red], Thick, l}, 0]
```

[image]

Comment: None of these seem to work for me. I just get blank plots I think it might be related to the sigma part in that it is not a defined expression in my case but an evaluated one from 

`growthrate = Solve[(k2 + sigma )*(k2 + (sigma/(nu/kappa)))*(k2) + (N2/(kappa*nu)* kH) == 0, sigma]; growthratearray = growthrate[[All, 1, 2]]; sigma = Max[ Re[growthratearray[[1]]], Re[growthratearray[[2]]]];`

I am trying the 1st method using mesh functions and get the warning "*sigma equation* is not a valid mesh"